# Extract element from a list inside a cell in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks something like that:

### Current dataframe

```
         col 1                          col 2

["item - 1", "item - 2"]       ["item - 3", "item - 4"]
```

How can i extract items from this dataframe so that I end up with items as column headers and number of times they occur in each row for col 1 and col 2

### Desired dataframe

```
         col 1                    col 2                    item1 item2 item3 item4

   
["item - 1", "item - 2"]       ["item - 3"]                  1     1     1     0
["item - 1"]                   ["item - 3", "item - 4"]      1     0     1     1
["item - 1", "item - 2"]       ["item - 3", "item - 4"]      1     1     1     1
```

I've tried multiple methods but each time I get an error: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 0):

Working with lists and strings in `pandas` is never efficient. But you can still use them..

Using [`sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html)

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(ds['col 1'].add(ds['col 2'])), 
             columns=mlb.classes_, 
             index=df.index)


    item - 1    item - 2    item - 3    item - 4
0   1           1           1           0
1   1           0           1           1
```

Using a pure pandas approach also works, but is slow..

```
ds.a.add(ds.b).astype(str).str.replace(' - ', '').str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(sep=', ')

    item1    item2  item3    item4
0   1        1      1        0
1   1        0      1        1
```